# sendResponse not waiting for async function or Promise's resolve

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having an issue of asynchronicity (I believe). `sendResponse()` in **contentscript.js** does not wait for `getThumbnails()` to return.

I am sending a *message* in **popup.js**:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "get_thumbnails", tabUrl: tabs[0].url},
      function (respThumbnails) {
            const thumbUrl = respThumbnails.payload;
            console.log("payload", thumbUrl)   
      }
);
```

Then, in **contentscript.js** I *listen* for this message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    if(request.message === "get_thumbnails") {
        const payload = await getThumbnails();
        console.log("thumbPayload after function:", payload)
        sendResponse({payload:payload});   
    }
});


async function getThumbnails() {
    let tUrl = null;
    var potentialLocations = [
        {sel: "meta[property='og:image:secure_url']",   attr: "content" },
        {sel: "meta[property='og:image']",              attr: "content" },
    ];

    for(s of potentialLocations) {
        if(tUrl) return
        const el = document.querySelector(s.sel);
        if(el) {
            tUrl = el.getAttribute(s.attr) || null;
        } 
    }
    return tUrl;
};
```

But it is also possible that the problem is coming from my `getThumnails()` function, because most of the times, **payload is null** and not undefined. So `getThumbnails()` might return before it is completely executed. 
If this is the case, I have no idea why...

I also tried this code for `getThubnails()`:

```
async function getThumbnails() {
  let x = await function() {
    let tUrl = null;
    var potentialLocations = [
        {sel: "meta[property='og:image:secure_url']",   attr: "content" },
        {sel: "meta[property='og:image']",              attr: "content" },
    ];

    for(s of potentialLocations) {
        if(tUrl) return
        const el = document.querySelector(s.sel);
        if(el) {
            tUrl = el.getAttribute(s.attr) || null;
        } 
    }
    return tUrl;
  }
  return x;
};
```

But this does not work, it seems to break my code...

Comment: BTW, document.querySelector doesn't return a Promise so there's no sense in awaiting it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Chrome still doesn't support Promise in the returned value of onMessage listener both in ManifestV3 and V2**. Click the star in https://crbug.com/1185241 to be notified of progress.

Since your listener is declared with `async` keyword, it returns a `Promise`, not a literal `true` value as [required](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) by onMessage implementation, so the returned Promise with your value is just ignored, the port is immediately closed, and the caller receives `undefined` in response.

#### Making your listener compatible

1. Remove the `async` keyword from before `(request, sender, sendResponse)`
2. Declare a separate `async` function and call it from the onMessage listener:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
     if (msg.message === "get_thumbnails") {
       processMessage(msg).then(sendResponse);
       return true; // keep the messaging channel open for sendResponse
     }
   });

   async function processMessage(msg) {
     console.log('Processing message', msg);
     // .................
     return 'foo';
   }
   ```

#### Patching the API to allow an async/Promise listener

Add the following at the beginning of each script that uses chrome.runtime.onMessage

```js
if ('crbug.com/1185241') { // replace with a check for Chrome version that fixes the bug
  const {onMessage} = chrome.runtime, {addListener} = onMessage; 
  onMessage.addListener = fn => addListener.call(onMessage, (msg, sender, respond) => {
    const res = fn(msg, sender, respond);
    if (res instanceof Promise) return !!res.then(respond, console.error);
    if (res !== undefined) respond(res);
  });
}
```

...and then you can simply `return` the value:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async msg => {
  if (msg === 'foo') {
    const res = await fetch('https://foo/bar');
    const payload = await res.text();
    return {payload};
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have tried with your code and it still does not work. it returns null. Is everthing fine with my getThumbnails() function? Beside the await document.querySelector, which I removed :)

Comment: When you edit content scripts you need to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and also reload the web page where that content script runs. As for that function, I don't see anything that needs `async` and `await` inside at all.

Comment: Yes of course, I reload the extension and refresh the page all the time. Your code is actually working, but the reason why I am still having an issue is because the page I am on has like 6 or 7 frames. As I have "all_frames"=true in my manifest, a new message is send for each of the frames, and all of them sendResponse to my popup.js, but popup.js receives only 1 response, even tough 6 were sent... I don't know if I am clear or not, but for instance, I do     console.log("location:", document.location) in my contentscript, and it consoles log 6 different locations... I cannot find a solution..

Comment: The iframe issue is a different question. Off the top of my head, you can simply add a runtime.onMessage listener in your popup and use runtime.sendMessage in your content script instead of sendResponse. Or you can switch to tabs.executeScript instead of declared content scripts with messaging, so you'll collect the output from all frames in one array.

Comment: I have the same code in a popup window and a browser action menu, and an onMessage handler in a persistent background page. Weirdly, after making the handler async, the popup worked perfectly. It was only after going back to test the menu that I realized something had broken. If the popup wasn't also open, the menu worked fine. But if it was, awaited async calls to the background made from the menu never received responses. Something about having two pages open (and two ports) seemed to break it. Moving the awaits out of the handler fixed things.

Comment: @jdunning, it means there was another mistake in your code that was canceled out. There's no point in discussing it without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: This didn't work for me until I removed the `async` keyword within the top-level `addListener` function. `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (` >>> `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (`

Comment: @Vadorequest, you did exactly what this answer is showing. I've added an explicit note to clarify it.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I just struggled to reproduce exactly the same thing, as I started from existing code I didn't notice the `async` keyword was there and I thought your solution didn't work, until I spotted/removed it.

Comment: You just saved me! For future readers, REMOVE THE ASYNC!!! Use thens, the sendReponse and the return true and it will solve all your problems!

Comment: Solution 1 didn't work for me. Solution 2 did the trick! Cleaner too.

Comment: How did you know `return true` is to keep the channel open, I cannot see that is mentioned anywhere in the document...such important thing..

Comment: @Arst, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314359857