# Chrome event listener SendResponse not sending even though I return true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Running into the same problem as [Chrome Extension Message passing: response not sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077487/chrome-extension-message-passing-response-not-sent). But when I implement the solution suggested it doesn't fix my issue. I'm getting the exact same error and also calling an async method before returning a response. What is going wrong here???

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    async function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.action === "getAllTabs") {
            // if I uncomment this line, content.js receives this response
            // sendResponse({data: "hey"})
            chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
                // but not this one??
                sendResponse({data: tabs});
            })
            console.log('returning true');
            return true;
```

my content.js:

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getAllTabs"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return `true`, it returns a `Promise`, see the linked topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome extension - sendResponse not waiting for async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024819/chrome-extension-sendresponse-not-waiting-for-async-function)

Comment: It does. My understanding of async functions was lacking, I actually didn't even realize that function was async. Thanks