# Where can I properly use the API "chrome.downloads" when I want to download?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

## Ⅰ. Introduction

I have read a lot and tried various ways of using the `chrome.downloads` API. But until now, I am still helpless in finding a way to use the `chrome.downloads` API.

Instructions from [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download) didn't seem to help me much. So I decided to come here to ask and present to everyone about the problem that I am facing. I hope it helps many people.

My project uses manifest version 3.

Here is the GitHub link of the project: https://github.com/ATU8020/Use-API-chrome.downloads.git

## Ⅱ. Presenting the Problem

Some related concepts are used:

1. Service worker
2. Content script
3. Asynchronous function
4. Synchronous function

### Problems

I know that service workers require asynchronous function.

> Listeners must be registered synchronously from the start of the page. [LINK](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#:%7E:text=Listeners%20must%20be%20registered%20synchronously%20from%20the%20start%20of%20the%20page.)

> Do not register listeners asynchronously, as they will not be properly triggered. [LINK](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#:%7E:text=Do%20not%20register%20listeners%20asynchronously%2C%20as%20they%20will%20not%20be%20properly%20triggered.)

But the `chrome.downloads.download` API returns a `Promise`:

[image: API Chrome.downloads]

[See `chrome.downloads` docs.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download)

That confused me. I have also tried other ways, such as with the content script. But after reading the docs, I know that the API `chrome.downloads` cannot be used directly.
[image]

[See content script docs.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#:%7E:text=Content%20scripts%20are%20unable%20to%20access%20other%20APIs%20directly.)

### Comment

That is the crux of my question. Any constructive comments and useful information are always appreciated.

## Ⅲ. More Information

If using the API `chrome.downloads` in file `popup.js` it works; what does that mean?

I know that could be an alternative solution.

But what if you want to do something like `download` when you click on a `contextMenu`? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Use `onMessage`/`sendMessage` to communicate between different contexts. For example, if you present a button in a context that doesn't support `.downloads`, using messaging to communicate with a context that does support `.downloads` and then use that context to actually do the download.

Comment: @Ouroborus The problem is what is the context in which you say API `chrome.downloads` can be used?

Comment: Any of the contexts that are under control of the extension. This would usually be background, popup, and content-script. (This does not include scripts that have been injected into the page by, for example, creating and inserting a script element directly in the page.) Note that a lot of the functions meant for use with extensions return promises. You'll need to get familiar with asynchronous programming to work with them.

Comment: @Ouroborus "content-script" when inserted as API `chrome.scripting` also didn't work in my case, I tried.

Comment: Yeah, that's injection, not a content-script. A content-script is declared in the manifest and automatically handled.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the method returns a Promise is not related to the way the listeners are **registered**.
You can call asynchronous code inside the listener in the background script.

- ignoring the result:

  ```js
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(info => {
    chrome.downloads.download({url: info.linkUrl});
  });
  ```
- using the result:

  ```js
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async info => {
    const downloadId = await chrome.downloads.download({url: info.linkUrl});
    console.log('downloadId:', downloadId);
  });
  ```

  Beware: `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener doesn't work with `async` functions yet, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024910).

Comment: I don't understand how your solution works in my case. I have tried and still not getting the expected result. If possible, please explain in detail for me to understand.

Comment: Project is quite simple if you find it necessary. https://github.com/ATU8020/Use-API-chrome.downloads

Comment: I guess you integrated it incorrectly so show your final code at the end of the question.

Comment: https://github.com/ATU8020/Use-API-chrome.downloads/blob/main/background.js

Comment: On StackOverflow all related code/info should be inside the question.