# chrome extension `sendResponse` does not work. Service Worker | Menisfest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have read tons of answers in stackoverflow but problem still exists.

Also went through the question [chrome extension - sendResponse not waiting for async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024819/chrome-extension-sendresponse-not-waiting-for-async-function)
I implemented that but it doesn't work.
I have to use the `async` function inside add event listener where I have to do API calls. If I will not use that and handle it with promise still I have to wait. How to wait for the response then?

in Background.js (service worker)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (object, sender, sendResponse) => {
if (object.id === 'checkUser') {
    const { config: { url, token } } = object;
    try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetch(`https://${url}/api/check`, {
      
            method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
        });
        const result = await fetchResponse.json()
        if (result.status) {
            sendResponse({ status: true, message: 'Exist' })
            return true 
        } else {
            sendResponse({ status: false, message: 'Not exists' })
            return true
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        sendResponse({ status: false, message: 'Unable to check user', error: error })
    }
    // return true
} else {
    sendResponse({ status: false })
    return true
}
```

})

in popup.js

```
 await chrome.storage.local.get(['url', 'token', 'user'], async (res) => {
  const { token, url, user } = res
  if (token && url) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      id: 'checkUser',
      config: {
        token, url
      }
    }, (response) => {
      console.log(response, 'inside Popup') \\ returns undefined

    })
  }
})
```

I have tried toggling `return true` inside the onMessage.addListener. No error.,
Sometimes it shows

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Comment: did my answer fix your issue?

Comment: No, not yet. @VinodLiyanage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024910/9801711 This helped me on this.